# Member reference base type is not a structure or a union

Tags: c++, arrays

I need some help with a problem I'm having with my homework assignment.

```
//finds frequency of a sequence in an array (including mutations)
int find_freq_with_mutations(string target,string sequences[],int sequences_length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sequences_length; i++) { //goes through each sequence in array
        string current_sequence = sequences[i]; //sets current sequence as a string
        for (int j = 0; j < current_sequence.length(); j++) { //iterate for every character in sequence
            if (current_sequence[j] == current_sequence[j+1]) {
                current_sequence[j].erase();
            }
        }
    }
    int target_frequency = find_frequency(target, sequences, sequences_length);

    return target_frequency;

}
```

The error message is:

```
DNA_sequencing.cpp:70:24: error: member reference base type
      'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type' (aka 'char') is not a structure or
      union
                                current_sequence[j].erase();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Here `current_sequence[j].erase();` it seems you are want to erase a character but your code is calling erase on a character itself. I think you need to write something like this `current_sequence.erase(current_sequence.begin() + j);`

Comment: You're asking about an error message referencing an object whose declaration is not even shown, not to mention the fact that the shown code fails to meet all requirements of a [mre] as explained in the stackoverflow.com's [help]. Unfortunately, this means that the only thing that anyone will be able to tell you is the same thing that your compiler is telling you: "current_sequence[j]", whatever it is, is not a structure or a union. For more informationl, see [ask] questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your code shows indicates that you are trying to call `erase()` on a character in an `std::string`. If you wish to erase a character in a string, you need to call the `erase()` function in `std::string`. I recommend using iterators to loop through your string, since using the `erase()` function on a string that you're iterating through with integer indices would be difficult, since the index of each character in the string changes every time you erase a character. Taking this into account, the inner for loop becomes:

```
for (auto it = current_sequence.begin(); it != current_sequence; ) {
      if (*it == *(it + 1)) {
           it = current_sequence.erase(it);
      } else {
           it++;
      }
}
```

Another note is that if you plan on mutating the strings in the array you should probably be using a pointer or reference, since `current_sequence` is just a copy of the string in the array. Since you're already using an array, I recommend looping through the string pointers themselves, like so:

```
for (std::string *current_sequence = sequences; current_sequence < sequences + sequences_length; current_sequence++) {
    /* Do something with current_sequence */
}
```